# Error: Permission denied Firebase crear/sobreescribir documento

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic, firestore

Soy bastante novato tanto en angular como firebase / firestore y me encuentro encallado con el siguiente error.

Este fragmento de código permite realizar un registro nuevo de un usuario dentro de mi aplicación.

```
register() {
    // console.log(this.registerCode);
    this.authService.checkKey(this.registerCode).subscribe((dSnap) => {
      if (dSnap.data() !== undefined){

        const data = dSnap.data();
        this.regDoc.used = data.used;
        this.regDoc.user = data.user;
        // console.log(this.regDoc.used);
        if (!this.regDoc.used && this.regDoc.user === '') {
          this.authService.register(this.username, this.password1).subscribe(
            resData => {
              console.log(resData);
              // let newUsr = new User(resData.localId, this.username, resData.refreshToken, null);
              let authObs: Observable<AuthResponseData>;
              authObs = this.authService.login(this.username, this.password1);

              authObs.subscribe(
                resData => {
                  console.log(resData);
                  this.authService.createUser(this.username, resData.localId).then(uSnap => {
                    console.log(uSnap);
                    this.regDoc.user = this.username;
                    this.regDoc.used = true;
                    this.authService.updateKey(this.registerCode, this.regDoc);

                    this.router.navigateByUrl('tasks');
                  });

                },
                errRes => {
                  const code = errRes.error.error.message;
                  let message = 'No se ha podido iniciar sesion, vuelve a intentarlo';
                  if (code === 'INVALID_EMAIL'){
                    message = 'Email no encontrado';
                  } else if (code === 'INVALID_PASSWORD'){
                    message = 'Contraseña incorrecta';
                  }
                  alert(message);
                }
              );

              // this.router.navigateByUrl('tasks');
            },
            errRes => {
              const code = errRes.error.error.message;
              let message = 'No se ha podido registrar, vuelve a intentarlo.';
              if (code === 'EMAIL_EXISTS') {
                message = 'Esta direccion de correo ya existe.';
              }
              alert(message);
            }
          )
          // console.log(this.regDoc.user);
        }
        else {
          alert('El codigo no es válido.')
        }
      } else {
        alert('El codigo no es válido.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Su funcionamiento es el siguiente:

1. Primero se comprueba si existe una clave de registro dentro de la colección de `registerKeys` en firebase
2. Si es correcta la clave, se registra el usuario
3. Se realiza un login
4. Se crea un registro dentro de la colección `users` con los datos de ese usuario.
5. Se actualizan los datos de la clave de registro en la colección `registerKeys`

Con las reglas de firestore de test (permiso total de escritura y lectura) no existe problema y todo el proceso se realiza correctamente.

El error surge cuando en la base de datos de producción, se realiza el mismo proceso, estas son las reglas:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /registerKeys/{key} {
        allow read;
      allow write;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow read: if request.auth != null
            && (resource == null 
                || request.auth.uid == userId);
    }
    match /users/{uid}/tasks/{task} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;      
    }
    match /users/{uid}/customers/{customer} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Como se puede ver, solo se permite el crear y actualizar si el `id` de la `request` coincide con el id del documento que se quiere modificar.

Pero con esta configuración, cuando intento ejecutarlo, recibo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
e@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:92229:23
430/So</u.prototype.Oi/<@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:102005:34
T/<@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:101953:22
tb@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113128:22
E@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113108:50
2870/Z.prototype.sa@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:114119:34
qc@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113463:138
sc@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113356:31
2870/h.Ca@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113329:35
2870/h.Xa@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113291:83
tb@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113128:22
E@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113108:50
zd@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113761:19
2870/h.Ua@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113756:24
2870/h.za@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113755:78
wrapFn@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10652:43
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10283:35
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:68267:33
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10282:64
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10054:51
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneTask</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10365:38
invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11505:18
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11531:31
EventListener.handleEvent*customScheduleGlobal@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11657:47
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10270:30
onScheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10160:84
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10263:55
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10097:47
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.scheduleEventTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10123:29
makeAddListener/<@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11814:37
patchProperty/desc.set@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10713:24
2870/h.ba@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113723:33
lc@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113290:419
Md@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:114000:361
2870/h.Aa@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113993:39
Fb@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113155:13
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10249:30
onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:68280:33
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10248:56
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10009:47
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11167:38
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10283:35
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:68267:33
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10282:64
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10054:51
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10469:39
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneTask</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10369:25
invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11505:18
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11531:31
EventListener.handleEvent*customScheduleGlobal@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11657:47
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10270:30
onScheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10160:84
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10263:55
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10097:47
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.scheduleEventTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10123:29
makeAddListener/<@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11814:37
patchProperty/desc.set@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10713:24
2870/h.ba@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113723:33
lc@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113290:377
jc@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113289:70
2870/h.Ba@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113960:94
Fb@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:113155:13
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10249:30
onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:68280:33
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10248:56
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10009:47
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11167:38
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10283:35
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:68267:33
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10282:64
9140/</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10054:51
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10469:39
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneTask</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10369:25
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10354:52
scheduleTask/data.args[0]@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:12912:36
setTimeout handler*scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:12914:39
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10270:30
onScheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10160:84
9140/</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.scheduleTask@http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10263:55
```

Servicio `auth.service.ts`:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { User } from './../models/user';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, from} from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Storage } from '@capacitor/storage';

export interface AuthResponseData {
  kind: string;
  idToken: string;
  email: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  localId: string;
  expiresIn: string;
  registered?: boolean;
}

export interface RegisterKeyData {
  used : boolean;
  user : string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private _user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
  private userDataLogged = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

  currentEvent = this.userDataLogged.asObservable();

  publish(param):void{
    this.userDataLogged.next(param);
  }

  get userIsAuthenticated() {
    return this._user.asObservable().pipe(
      map(user => {
        if (user) {
          return !!user.token;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  get userEmail() {
    return this._user.asObservable().pipe(
      map(user => {
        if (user) {
          return user.email;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  get userId() {
    return this._user.asObservable().pipe(
      map(user => {
        if (user) {
          return user.id;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore
    ) { }

  autoLogin() {
    return from(Storage.get({key: 'authData'}))
    .pipe(map(storedData => {
      if (!storedData || !storedData.value)  {
        return null;
      }
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData.value) as {
        userId: string;
        token: string;
        tokenExpirationDate: string;
        email: string;
      }

      const expirationTime = new Date(parsedData.tokenExpirationDate);
      if (expirationTime <= new Date()) {
        return null;
      }

      const user = new User(
        parsedData.userId,
        parsedData.email,
        parsedData.token,
        expirationTime
      )

      return user;
    }),
    tap(user => {
      if (user) {
        this._user.next(user);
      }
    }),
    map(user => {
      this.publish({user:"logged"});
      return !!user;
    })
    )
  }

  login(user: string, password: string){
    return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>(
      `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=${environment.firebaseConfig.apiKey}`,
      {email: user, password, returnSecureToken: true})
      .pipe(tap(this.setUserData.bind(this)));
  }

  logout() {
    // this._userIsAuthenticated = false;
    this._user.next(null);
  }

  private setUserData(userData: AuthResponseData) {
    const expirationTime = new Date(
      new Date().getTime() + +userData.expiresIn * 1000
    );
    this._user.next(
      new User(
        userData.localId,
        userData.email,
        userData.idToken,
        expirationTime
      )
    );
    this.storeAuthData(
      userData.localId,
      userData.idToken,
      expirationTime.toISOString(),
      userData.email
    );

    this.publish({user:"logged"});
  }

  private storeAuthData(
    userId: string,
    token: string,
    tokenExpirationDate: string,
    email: string
  ){
    const data = JSON.stringify({userId, token, tokenExpirationDate, email});
    Storage.set({key: 'authData', value: data});
  }

  //Register new user
  register(email: string, password: string){
    return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>(
      `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=
      ${environment.firebaseConfig.apiKey}`,
      {email: email, password: password, returnSecureToken: true}
    );
  }

  createUser(userName: string, usrId: string){
    console.log(userName, usrId);
    let currentId;
    this.userId.subscribe(userId=> currentId = userId );
    console.log('current id: ' + currentId);
    return this.angularFirestore.collection('users').doc(usrId).set(
      {
        user: userName,
        active: true,
        tier: ''
      });
  }

  checkKey(regKey: string){
    return this.angularFirestore.collection('registerKeys').doc<RegisterKeyData>(regKey).get();
  }

  updateKey(regKey: string, regData: RegisterKeyData){
    return this.angularFirestore.collection('registerKeys').doc<RegisterKeyData>(regKey).update(regData);
  }
}
```

Comment: En qué parte del código tienes el error?

Comment: En la linia `this.authService.createUser(this.username, resData.localId)`

Comment: Por favor comparte el código de `authService`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras investigar, he conseguido encontrar la solución, por lo que parece, es un error comun en la versión que tenia instalada de [angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) (la librería oficial de google firebase para angular), es una incidencia que se explica en su [repositorio](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2838).

La solución que ha servido es la siguiente, reducir la versión con problemas (en mi caso la **8.6.3**) a una mas estable, que es la **8.6.1**:

Para ello, en un terminal eliminamos la versión antigua con `npm`:

```
npm uninstall firebase
```

Y seguidamente

```
npm install --save firebase@8.6.1
```